# How to append --query parameter in AWS python SDK?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I would like to collect the total size of a bucket for AWS S3. Of course I can do this by using aws-cli:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket MYBUCKET --query "[Sum(Contents[].Size)]"
```

But my question is: how can I append `--query` in python SDK? I have checked boto documentation but haven't found a way to do this.

Some sample code:

```
s3_conn = S3Connection(aws_access_key_id="KEY",aws_secret_access_key'AC_KEY')
buckets = s3_conn.get_all_buckets()
# I can list all items
items = buckets[0].list()
# but how can I append --query "[Sum(Contents[].Size)]" to here?
```

Comment: The ``--query`` parameter is specific to the AWS CLI.  It is implemented by taking the raw output of the botocore call and processing it with [jmespath](http://jmespath.org).  You could get similar results by using those two components yourself.

Comment: Hi @garnaat. Using `--query` to sum up the size is super fast when there are lots of objects (compared with using `bucket.list()` in SDK). So I think by using `--query`, it is AWS server who does the sum job. If this is true, is there a way we can ask AWS server to do this by using SDK? Really thank for your answer :)

Comment: No, the ``--query`` option is handled on the client side.  There is no server-side support for that in the S3 service.

Answer (score 1):

You want to run JMESPath query on results. Althoug aws-sdk does it seamlessly but its not part of AWS API, boto3 is quite a thin wrapper around it, you can do the same via python library.

```
import boto3
import jmespath

result_query = jmespath.compile("[sum(Contents[].Size), length(Contents[])]")
client = boto3.client('s3').list_objects(Bucket="MYBUCKET")
filtered_result = result_query.search(client)
print(filtered_result)
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects.html there is no `query` parameter in `list-objects`

Comment: yes, but the example in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects.html#list-the-objects-in-a-bucket uses `--query`. So I wonder how could I implement similar feature in the code level. Thanks.